# WebSockets - ASP.NET 4.5 IIS 8 Final Release

Tags: websocket, asp.net-4.5, iis-8

All the blogs online have been in reference to the beta with the old namespaces and use nuget packages. Im trying to get a simple low level websockets example going based on whats in the wild now and its just not working.

The client is never able to establish a connection. The error from the chrome debug console is:
"Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. "

However, I know the request is being received because I put code in my ashx handler to email me at various points just to confirm the request was coming in and my task was firing etc.

Config - All Final Release Versions:
Windows Server 2012/IIS 8/ ASP.NET 4.5

My sample is based on:
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097383

The handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebSockets;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myWebSocket
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for wsHandler
/// </summary>
public class wsHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        // context.Response.Write("Hello World");


        context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(MyWebSocketTask);
    }

    public async Task MyWebSocketTask(WebSocketContext context)
    {
        WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;


        while (true)
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("email@address.com");
            message.Subject = "Handler";
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("michaelo@hostcollective.com");
            message.Body = string.Format("Task Launched {0}", socket.State.ToString());
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("localhost");
            smtp.Send(message);


            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);

            // Asynchronously wait for a message to arrive from a client
            WebSocketReceiveResult result =
                    await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

            // If the socket is still open, echo the message back to the client
            if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                string userMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0,
                        result.Count);
                userMessage = "You sent: " + userMessage + " at " +
                        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userMessage));

                // Asynchronously send a message to the client
                await socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                        true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else { break; }
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

As for the client, this is the simplest one based on the stuff at websockets.org

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

// var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
var wsUri = "ws://iis8hosting.com/mikey/wshandler.ashx";
var output;

function init() {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
}

function testWebSocket() {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);       

    websocket.onopen = function (evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function (evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function (evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function (evt) { onError(evt) };
}

function onOpen(evt) {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
}

function onClose(evt) {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
}

function onMessage(evt) {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>');
    websocket.close();
}

function onError(evt) {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
}

function doSend(message) {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
}

function writeToScreen(message) {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

```
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2><div id="output"></div>
```

Anybody have any ideas or another simple sample such as this that is confirmed to work with the final release stuff. Thanks for taking the time to read and respond.

Answer (score 0):

I could make your code work with some changes in your code.
 You may not require to do all of the below changes in your environment.
**On Server side**

put a try catch block around SMTP code

Verify context.IsWebSocketConnection is true

if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
   {
      context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(MyWebSocketTask);
   }
   else
   {
      throw new HttpException("This isn't a WebSocket request!");
   }

**On client side:** 
I changed code like below based on errors i got :). 
This code will work in IISExpress 8 as well.
  var wsUri = "ws://<%: Request.Url.Host %>:<%: Request.Url.Port %><%: 
Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/wshandler.ashx")

1. Added serverData inside form like below.
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div id="serverData"></div>
   </form>
   And used it in writeToScreen() function.
   function writeToScreen(message) {
   var serverData = document.getElementById("serverData");
   var newElem = document.createElement("p");
   newElem.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
   newElem.innerHTML = message;
   serverData.insertBefore(newElem, serverData.firstChild);
   }
2. onMessage() function closes the connection from client side. So only one message is sent and received.
3. Make sure the IE10 browser's document mode is "Standard". I used IE10 for testing your code.

Comment: Thank you Anand! Unfortunately, I implemented your changes and it still isnt working. Same behavior. I also moved the smtp stuff within the if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open) block and an email is never even generated. Were you testing against ws://iis8hosting.com:80/mikey/wshandler.ashx or just locally with this code? Other than enabling webosockets server side, is there something else that must be done?

Comment: I tried locally on my win8 box. then it looks like your win8 server is not configured properly for web socket.

Comment: @user1713321 - Is there a proxy or firewall sitting between the client and the server?  Most proxies and firewalls do not yet allow WebSockets connections and will reject them.  Try making sure that the client has a *direct* connection to the server.

Comment: Great question. I initially thought this may be an issue as well so I tried hitting the page from the server itself and had the same issue.

Comment: Enable Freb logging on IIS and see what kind of errors you are seeing in the logs related to websocket. like handshake failure?

Comment: Strange thing is that Im not getting a log for the websocket request. Only for the aspx or html page. However when I run fiddler, Its showing a 504 for the request to the handler: HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 12:28:41.385

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

Comment: did you enable websocket in IIS?[Link](http://www.paulbatum.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-websockets-in.html)

Comment: Yes. Websocket Protocol is enabled under the web server role.